# Управление vk видео через js

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Хочу на свой сайт вставить видео из vk, а потом например узнать текущую позицию видео. Как это можно сделать?

Сайт на чистом html, видео идет нормально, но никак не могу найти какой-нибудь обьект наподобие vk или video_player, через который можно прочитать текущее время ролика.

Как я вижу, при вставке через iframe все видео внутри этого ифрейма, в том числе глобальные переменные, которые описывают все подряд, а доступа к ним нет из-за правил CORS.

Comment: Я вас поздравляю, вы в своем вопросе сразу поняли почему это не реализуемо в текущем исполнении, последний абзац прям в точку :)

Comment: Ну это конечно отлично. Но может есть все-таки какой-нибудь путь. К примеру youtube api позволяет создать плеер и управлять им через js, чтобы все-таки как то управлять видео.